# Does the NVIDIA Quadro FX 5600 1.5 GB. meet Blender 2.8 minimum system requirements?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT 512 MB witch runs problem less Blender 2.7, but as much as I tried to run Blender 2.8, it does not work.
I have considered to buy an NVIDIA Quadro FX 5600 1.5 GB. but I need to be sure that it runs Blender 2.8.
Has anyone tried it out?
I hope to get an answer soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about that specific card but it should work even if it is legacy (cycles GPU compute may not work Eevee will still work). I have a  Quadro 2000 and blender works fine on mine (for most work loads). After looking at comparisons between the 2 the Quadro FX 5600 is better than mine therefore it should work with blender.[image: The comparisons]
Graphics support
[image: Minimum requirements]
[image: The opengl support]

Comment: Thanks a lot for being that fast, but I forgot to mention that I would use it on Mac (Mac pro early 2008) do you think it will still work

Comment: Here are some threads most say basically if you buy the mac compatible version It should be fine but check I'm not sure. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6679157 https://forums.appleinsider.com/discussion/81477/nvidia-quadro-fx-5600-inside-macpro